# Disable Foxit PDF reader Support Popup

Tags: foxit-reader

With latest update of Foxit PDF reader 2023.3.0.23028, I now see this pop up with headphone/mic avatar on the bottom right:

[image]

I looked for options to disable this but could not find any. Does any one know how to disable this?

Comment: When do you get this icon and could you include a screenshot of the entire window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open File -> Preferences.
2. (Optional) Search for `support`.
3. Click General. Scroll down to `Application Startup`.
4. Enable `Disable Support Center`. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
5. Restart the app.

[image]